# ParseError in Android Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am new to Android and in my app, I'm using Volley for integrating WebServices and I have to send `AccessToken` to server and I'm passing it to the server through header, but when I run my app, I am getting `ParseError`. Please help.

**MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        makeJsonObjReq();
    }

    private void makeJsonObjReq() {

        JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
        try {
            request.put("TripStatus", "-1");
            request.put("MedicaidId", "10251025");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BackGroundPostServiceClass.makeJsonObjeRequest(MainActivity.this, request, "My url");
    }
```

**BackGroundPostServiceClass**:

```
public class BackGroundPostServiceClass {

    public static GetBatchDetails getProductDetailsImpl;
    public static ProgressDialog pd;

    public static void makeJsonObjeRequest(
            final Context context, JSONObject jsonObject, String url) {

        getProductDetailsImpl = ((GetBatchDetails) context);
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Alert", "Please Wait...");

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(
                url, jsonObject,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        pd.dismiss();
                        getProductDetailsImpl.getBatchDetails(response.toString());
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                pd.dismiss();

                if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {

                    showSignOutAlertDialog(context, "TimeoutError");

                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    showSignOutAlertDialog(context, "AuthFailureError");

                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {

                    showSignOutAlertDialog(context, "ServerError");

                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {

                    showSignOutAlertDialog(context, "NetworkError");
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {

                    showSignOutAlertDialog(context, "ParseError");
                }
            }

        }) {

            /**
             * Passing some request headers
             * */
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();

                String accesstoken = "To6k4mxO0rqvhPVSeZZ5Jr8Ish35vwSUoaxjbQZNgNz2qTd3PO0M4yFPmMCX4B-wdgkLz-DBf-EuMUyQLQDld0inlT3Rm_yc3N4S4Kgjz9buLkHjN_CBxKbaZPaKmP4cxrzqA1KXSbik11OidFVZg1f8m9Ygnra_WL_2hzZE-p1VMDZoj2z0ojofHoVvfnRXv3UTfmlFuHBhCTWKtT2SSGYjwHKEjYqhtjiMhbZ91B8";
                headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + accesstoken);

                return headers;
            }

            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json";
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                int mStatusCode = response.statusCode;
                System.out.println("Status code is===>"+mStatusCode);
                return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
            }
        };

        jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
            @Override
            public int getCurrentTimeout() {
                return 150000;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
                return 150000;
            }

            @Override
            public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {

            }
        });

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }
}
```

**AppController**:

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                    new LruBitmapCache());
        }
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do provide the error logs.

Comment: what do u mean i am not understand

Comment: You said you're receiving a `ParseError`. Provide the logcat.

Comment: https://driverapitest.lcptransportation.com/MemberPortalAPI/api/Trip/GetTrips 0xa2fb81ae NORMAL 1> [lifetime=3279], [size=28138], [rc=200], [retryCount=150000]
06-17 10:11:53.567 6384-6426/com.example.venkat.volleyexample1 I/System.out: Status code is===>200
06-17 10:11:53.654 6384-6384/com.example.venkat.volleyexample1 D/Volley: [1] Request.finish: 3410 ms

Comment: You should edit your post and add the full logcat of the error.

Comment: in log cat it's showing nothing more than what i post

Comment: `Status code is===>200` that's successful response code

Answer (score 2):

as logs and BNK says the response is fine. you have the problem because you probably do not receive json object but smth else.

To debug further you can add

```
String jsonString =
                new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
System.out.println("Response is===>"+jsonString);
```

next to

> System.out.println("Status code is===>"+mStatusCode);